# ajax that worked repeatedly in jquery 1.3.2 only works first time in 1.7.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here's the code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $().ajaxStart(function(){
            alert("in ajaxStart")
            //tried removing $.blockUI( below, same thing. don't see alert
            //$.blockUI({ message: '<h1><img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" /> Running query...</h1>' }); 
        });
        $().ajaxStop(function(){
            $.unblockUI()
        });
    ...
        $("#frmQUERYSUBMIT").submit(function(e) {
    ...
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
              url:    '/execquery/' + jsonQuery,
              //datatype: JSON, //original, incorrect
              datatype: "json", //still get same problem with correct usage
              success: function(data, textStatus) {
                          $("#status p").html(data);
                       },
              async:   true
            });          
    ...
        });
    });
```

In 1.3.2, this worked fine, reached the server, gave me back the data I expected.  When I upgraded to 1.7.1, it works once (per opening of browser), but all subsequent executions do nothing.  If I step thru the code in firebug, it shows it going from line to line every time, but only actually does something the first time.  Also, in 1.7.1, `$().ajaxStart(` is also only run the first time, not any subsequent times.

TIA

EDIT: I had originally posted that my server logs showed no connection on subsequent attempts.  This was an error.  The logs show that a connection is made, and a response given.  It just doesn't show up in the browser.

EDIT: FWIW, in 1.3.2, the data comes back as `"{"queries":{"f.sp":{"1d":{"show_results":{"19820611":-2.6893769610040343,..."`; but in 1.7.1, it comes back as Document, and says that the type is `application/xml`

Comment: `datatype: JSON`: Where do you define the `JSON` variable? And `datatype` is not a valid option.

Comment: `datatype: JSON` should be changed to `dataType: "json"`. `async=true` isn't required as `true` is `async`'s default value.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ documents datatype option.  But the code I showed is wrong, should be dataType: "json".  I changed it, but it still doesn't work after first go.  No errors in firebug.

Answer (score 1):

JSON is not a valid datatype, try giving `datatype: 'json'`

Comment: Thanks, yes, I did try that (and edited my original post), but it didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Issue #1, the data not being available to javascript was solved by this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/250245/403748,

```
beforeSend: function(x) {
  if(x && x.overrideMimeType) {
   x.overrideMimeType("application/j-son;charset=UTF-8");
  }
 },
```

and issue #2 was solved by https://stackoverflow.com/a/4034337/403748

```
$(document).ajaxStart(
```

instead of
    $().ajaxStart(

Sorry for the time-waster...