# ajaxStart and ajaxStop not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In the beginning, I tried `ajaxStart` and `ajaxStop` in my page, and they did not work, the code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script language="javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form" method="post" action="">
    <input id = "name" type="text" name = "name" value="">
    <div id = "check"></div>
</form>

<script language="javascript">
       $("#name").blur(function() {
           $("#name").ajaxStart(function() {
               $("#check").html("loading...");
               alert("loading...");
           });
           $("#name").ajaxStop(function() {
               $("#check").html("OK...");
               alert("OK...");
           });
           $.ajaxSetup({
               url : "check.php",
               type : "POST",
               success : function(data) {
                   $("#check").html(data);
               },
           });
           $.ajax({
               url : "checkname.php",
               type : "POST",
               data : {name : $("#name").val()},
               datatype : "text",
               beforeSend : function() {
                   console.log("beforeSend");
               },
               success : function(data) {
                   $("#check").html(data);
                   console.log("success");
               },
               error : function() {
                   $("#check").html("error");
                   console.log("error");
               },
               complete : function() {
                   console.log("complete");
               },
           });
       });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Then, I found one answer [stackoverflow.com/questions/4034252/jquery-ajaxstart-not-working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034252/jquery-ajaxstart-not-working)
told me to use `document` instead, and when I used the following code it works

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
    $("#check").html("loading...");
    alert("loading...");   
});
```

Also, I tried another way, use jQuery 1.7.2 and it works on `$("#name").ajaxStart()`

My question are ：

1、Why in jQuery 1.11.1 the `$("#name").ajaxStart()` does not work, what has changed from 1.7.2?

2、Are there some websites to give me the difference of each version of jQuery, details will be better.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

1) As stated [here](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxstart/) in jQuery official documentation,
**As of jQuery 1.8, the .ajaxStart() method should only be attached to document.**

2) For your 2nd query, jQuery official documentation should be sufficient
For deprecated things go [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/)